# How to show list of recent chats on chat screen?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on `Flutter` application and creating a built in chat app for the application. I am not using shared preferences. I want to show all the recents chats on chat screens.
Like what's app, messenger when someone send you the message it appears in a `ListTile`.

Does anyone have related code or can tell me how to do it?

```
import 'package:bpe_application/chat/chatroom.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class Conversation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ConversationState createState() => _ConversationState();
}

class _ConversationState extends State<Conversation> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    setStatus("Online");
  }

  void setStatus(String status) async{
    await _firestore.collection('registration').doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid).update({
      "status": status,
    });


  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state){
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed){
      //online
      setStatus("Online");
    }else{
      //offline
      setStatus("Offline");
    }

  }

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Map<String, dynamic>? userMap;
  bool isLoading= false;
  final TextEditingController _search = TextEditingController();
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  String chatroomId(String user1, String user2){
   if(user1[0].toLowerCase().codeUnits[0] > user2.toLowerCase().codeUnits[0]){
     return "$user1$user2";
   }else{
     return "$user2$user1";
   }
  }


  void onSearch() async {
    FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    await _firestore.collection("registration").
    where("email", isEqualTo: _search.text).
    get().then((value) {
       setState(() {
        userMap= value.docs[0].data();
        isLoading=false;
      });
      print(userMap);

    }
    );

  }
  void listView() async {
    FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    await _firestore.collection("registration").
    where("email", isEqualTo: _search.text).
    get().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        userMap= value.docs[0].data();
        isLoading=false;
      });
      print(userMap);

    }
    );

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size= MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, //top bar color
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black, //bottom bar color
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ));
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Text(
            "Chat",
            style: GoogleFonts.limelight(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: isLoading? Center(
        child: Container(
        height: size.height/20,
          width: size.width/20,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
      )
          : ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
          topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
        ),
        child: Container(
          height: 800.0,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                height: size.height/14,
                width: size.width,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Container(
                  height: size.height/14,
                  width: size.width/1.2,
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _search,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Search",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      )
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: size.height/70,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: onSearch,
                  child: Text(
                    "Search",style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
              ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: size.height/60,
              ),
              userMap != null
                  ? ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  String roomId = chatroomId(
                      _auth.currentUser!.displayName!,
                      userMap!['name']);

                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => chatroom(
                        chatRoomId: roomId,
                        userMap: userMap!,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },


                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.account_box,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  userMap!['name'],
                  style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                  color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 17,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(userMap!['email']),
                trailing: Icon(
                  Icons.chat,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              )
                  : Container(),


            ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Here is my home/ chat screen code

**Here is my chatroom code**

```
 import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_chat_ui/flutter_chat_ui.dart';
    import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
    import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
    import 'package:path/path.dart';
    import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
    
    class chatroom extends StatelessWidget {
      final Map<String, dynamic> userMap;
      final String chatRoomId;
      chatroom({required this.chatRoomId, required this.userMap});
      final TextEditingController _message = TextEditingController();
      final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    
      File? imageFile;
    
      Future getImage() async {
        ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
        await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery).then((xFile) {
          if (xFile != null) {
            imageFile = File(xFile.path);
            uploadImage();
          }
        });
      }
    
      Future uploadImage() async {
        String fileName = Uuid().v1();
        int status = 1;
        await _firestore
            .collection("chatroom")
            .doc(chatRoomId)
            .collection('chats')
            .doc(fileName)
            .set({
          "sendBy": _auth.currentUser!.displayName,
          "message":"",
          "type":"img",
          "time": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });
        var ref =
            FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('images').child("$fileName.jpg");
        var uploadTask = await ref.putFile(imageFile!).catchError((error) async{
          await _firestore
              .collection("chatroom")
              .doc(chatRoomId)
              .collection('chats')
              .doc(fileName).delete();
    
          status = 0 ;
    
        });
        if(status==1){
          String imageUrl = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
          await _firestore
              .collection("chatroom")
              .doc(chatRoomId)
              .collection('chats')
              .doc(fileName).update({
            "message": imageUrl,
          });
          print(imageUrl);
        }
    
      }
    
      void onSendMessage() async {
        if (_message.text.isNotEmpty) {
          Map<String, dynamic> messages = {
            "sendBy": _auth.currentUser!.displayName,
            "message": _message.text,
            "type": "text",
            "time": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          };
          await _firestore
              .collection('chatroom')
              .doc(chatRoomId)
              .collection('chats')
              .add(messages);
          _message.clear();
        } else {
          print("Enter Some Text");
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
              child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                stream: _firestore
                    .collection("registration")
                    .doc(userMap['uid'])
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.data != null) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            userMap['name'],
                            style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 100),
                            child: Text(
                              snapshot.data!['status'],
                              style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 14,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Container();
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: size.height / 1.25,
                  width: size.width,
                  child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: _firestore
                        .collection('chatroom')
                        .doc(chatRoomId)
                        .collection('chats')
                        .orderBy("time", descending: false)
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.data != null) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            Map<String, dynamic> map = snapshot.data!.docs[index]
                                .data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                            return messages(size, map,context);
                          },
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Container();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            height: size.height / 10,
            width: size.width,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              height: size.height / 12,
              width: size.width / 1.1,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: size.height / 17,
                    width: size.width / 1.3,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _message,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () => getImage(),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.photo),
                        ),
                        hintText: "Send Message",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: onSendMessage,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget messages(Size size, Map<String, dynamic> map, BuildContext context) {
        return map['type'] == "text"
            ? Container(
                width: size.width,
                alignment: map['sendBy'] == _auth.currentUser!.displayName
                    ? Alignment.centerRight
                    : Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 14),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 8),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      map['message'],
                      style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Container(
                height: size.height / 2.5,
                width: size.width,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5,horizontal: 5),
                alignment: map['sendBy'] == _auth.currentUser!.displayName
                    ? Alignment.centerRight
                    : Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> ShowImage(imageURl: map['message'],
                    ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    height: size.height / 2.5,
                    width: size.width / 2,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(),
                    ),
                    alignment: map['message']!="" ? null :Alignment.center,
                    child: map['message'] != ""
                        ? Image.network(map['message'],fit: BoxFit.cover,)
                        : CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
      }
    }
    
    class ShowImage extends StatelessWidget {
      final imageURl;
      const ShowImage({required this.imageURl, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            height: size.height,
            width: size.width,
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Image.network(imageURl),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

I repeat I am not using shared preferences.

[I need the recent chats like that in the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwP9u.jpg)

Comment: Please show some code or describe what you have done so far to try to do this.

Comment: @Bellrampion please check now

Comment: @Bellrampion all things i do to add this i remove all of these as these are not working and it's the my 3rd day i am working on this but it's not doing anything

Comment: `orderBy("time", descending: false)` is it not working? did you debug?

Comment: @Manish yes it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at any code, I think the idea needs planning, and then routes towards that plan's completion.

An instant chat simulation turns out to be a stream of incoming data, and a list of recents chats is also a stream of incoming data.

The answer must be to code an instant message simulation, and to then code a stream that counts conversations.

That amounts to creating a stream of streams, where a list of conversations should be developed.

To have the above in mind before the coding begins is a good idea so that you know that after producing a single chat screen, that there's still more to go.

The next question will be, how to delete conversations from the list, like, is there a widget that helps slide them away like in Whatsapp?